# Linq to SQL code difference

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq-to-sql

A little new with Linq to SQL. I saw some code which is similar to the below example code and immediately wondered what is the difference between the two. At first i thought its the same but then wondered if this a preference by individual developers to get the same output or have i missed something?

I wasnt even sure what i could search on to see if anyone else has come across the same question so appreciate any explanation.

*Please note the code may not be 100% accurate but should give you an idea of what i am asking*

```
Public Function GetCustomerByID(Byval CustID as Integer) As IQueryable(Of Customer)
Return c From myDataContext.Customers Where c.ID = CustID Select c
End Function

Public Function GetCustomerByID(Byval CustID as Integer) As IQueryable(Of Customer)
Return myDataContext.Customers(Function(c) c.ID = CustID)
End Function
```

Comment: Difference is none, in second Lambda expression (or how it's called in vb) is used

Comment: Are you sure the second one does not have `Where` method call: `Return myDataContext.Customers.Where(Function(c) c.ID = CustID)` ?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek good point :) but if there were some `where` they would be the same :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are essentially the same in function, one simply uses the *Linq* (Language Integrated Query) proper and the other uses the exposed extension method(s); the extension methods are largely convenience methods (think shorthand queries) to do things which you would have to handcraft with Linq, but obviously even the more simple ones exist and these do tend to get uses quite often.

So, sometimes, usage of either is preference, and at other times using one or the other is objectively more appropriate for, say, means of ease of use, maintenance, etc.

<sub>It's worth noting that your example don't seem legitimate; as Marcin points out, your second example doesn't express usage of the extension methods I talk about: see `myDataContext.Customers.Where(Function(c) c.ID = CustID`.</sub>